# Oven thermostat replacement/substitute?

Tags: oven

I have an OLD Westinghouse "Continental" oven that has a faulty thermostat. The thermostat (see picture) [image]just "spins", and the temperature, if I am able to set one, is erratic - too hot or not hot enough! I was given a part number Q-25508, but it is no longer manufactured, so I am looking for a replacement part that I can substitute.

Comment: An appliance repair shop run by an old guy or an electrical supply store might be able to help to find a substitute.  I am just a touch older, but that oven probably works better than I do.

Comment: You may also be able to look up your oven's replacement parts on line, if you have it's model +and sometimes serial,) number, or if you can search for the part/style number stamped on the control's body. There are a fair number of repair-parts vendors with websites that can use these to look up the proper replacement.

Comment: What is the temperature range on the dial? Could you show a pic of the dial? Is this oven self cleaning?

Comment: You'd best hurry because even the concept of "appliance repair shop" is disappearing from the universe...

Answer (score 2):

Seven or eight years ago the digital oven timer/controller of our 30-year-old GE electric stove went out and a new one was no longer available. A friend referred me to a business in Ontario, Canada that rebuilds these. I sent them our timer; they repaired it and sent it back. It has worked perfectly ever since.

https://www.appliancetimers.com/